# Eliminate white space in between characters in PHP

Tags: php

lets say: 
"    i have            something          here, please     allow       me!    "

will become:
"i have something here, please allow me!"

Comment: Try look up preg_replace().

Answer (score 0):

Just use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (select all spaces (which comes more than one in a row) and replace it with a single space).

Example:

```
<?php
$str = "    i have       something       here, please allow      me!    ";
echo trim(preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $str));
```